# Batch to remove line - delete words in TXT

Tags: batch-file, cmd, edit

I'm making a script that creates a list of all HotFixes on a PC, and then proceeds to delete them (I need it, other tools like Windows Updates Uninstaller don't work).

Then:
My first Batch creates a temp file that contains all the Hotfixes

```
wmic qfe get "HotFixID" /format:table >%~dp0temp.txt
```

The problem is that the temp file created have this format

```
HotFixID   
KB2533552  
KB2884256  
KB2952664  
KB3020369  
KB3020370  
KB976002   
KB976902
```

And I need to delete the first line, and subsequent 2 characters of every other line, to look like this

```
2533552  
2884256  
2952664  
3020369  
3020370  
976002   
976902
```

I need this because my next script needs the ID of the update, and the KB is annoying.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly have the correct output from `Wmic` like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic qfe get "HotFixID" ^| findstr [0-9]') do (
  set "$Line=%%a"
  echo !$Line:~2!))>%~dp0temp.txt
```

Piping `wmic` against `findstr` with `RegExp` to check if the line contain a number and outputting the resulted lines without the 2 first char.

Comment: This is a very clean and simple solution. The only change I would recommend is to search off the first two characters to suppress any lines that do not have "KB" value as the first 2 characters; this will also strip off the first line.

Comment: Thanks @CoveGeek, that's effectively another way to do it. But you don't need to check the 2 fisrt characters in this specific case. Or you get KB12345 or nothing there is no third solution.

Comment: Your answer was so good, that I think you deserve the accepted answer, and I will not compete against you :)

Comment: Wonderful and elegant solution, my friend

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch regex processing utility for windows. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
wmic qfe get "HotFixID" | jrepl "^KB(\d+)" $1 /jmatch /o "%~dp0temp.txt"
```